# NSNotificiation and string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsnotificationcenter

I'm passing a string in one class to a `UILabel` in my view controller class. For some reason the string isn't being passed. when I check whats in the string it is 0x0

class.m

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notification"
                                                    object:self];

somestring = @"...";
```

ViewController.m

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleData:)
                                             name:@"notification"
                                           object:nil];

}
- (void)handleData:(NSNotification *)notification {


[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

    self.timerLabel.text =somestring;

}];
}
```

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException - breakpoint at label.text = class.somestring

Comment: check your label connection in .xib file

Comment: the label is connected in a storyboard and in . h: @property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

Comment: but you have mention your label name "lableinthisclass" in your code?
Please cross check

Comment: OK, so what's the reason given in the `NSException`?

Comment: I thought the label is initialised from the storyboard connection?

Comment: I didn't get you. your problem has been solved now?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[class copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c4c7e0'

Comment: I've initialised the class in view controller

Comment: i think setting value of label is NULL.

Comment: notification.object not having string value
Print value in nslog

Comment: Please try the following: lableinthisclass.text = self.class.somestring.description; I think the passed object is no NSString, but rather an NSDictionairy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784207/uilabel-copywithzone-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance

Might be help you

Answer (score 1):

You look to have a few issues:

I'm not sure why you are using `class` in `self.class.somestring`, I would expect it just to be `self.somestring`. If you have added a class method then the naming and intention is poor.

The notification object is a controller instance, so, using `self.class.somestring = notification.object;` will store that controller instance. Not a string. So, when you later do `lableinthisclass.text = self.class.somestring;` you are treating the controller instance as a string and getting an exception.

Consider whether the class interaction is correct and use a string where your code expects a string.

Comment: Okay thanks. removing the notification object stopped the exception.

Comment: I've updated the code to show even when I assign the string to the text it's not updating. Thanks.

Comment: `the string it is 0x0` => this means the string is `nil` and thus contains nothing...