# Add lots of button in UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, storyboard

I have this design in storyboard, it's all button which i stack simultaneously. But i have difficulty when i try to connect it to code, seems so repeated.

[image]

I have tried using regular drag-and-drop to connect all the buttons, but it seems so long and repeated.
is there best practice to connect and make one listener that could be listened by all of the buttons? using for-loop may be.

Comment: could you write it in swift? please, thank you.

Comment: The layout you have shown in this pic seems that collection view will be best suite for requirement, you can use UICollectionView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And u can just link them in storyboard.

Objective-C

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray * buttons;
```

Swift 2.2

```
@IBOutlet var collectionOfButtons = [UIButton]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionOfButtons.forEach {
        $0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(someFunc(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }
}
```

Or much simpler way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for view in view.subviews {
        (view as? UIButton)?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(someFunc(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }
}
func someFunc(sender: UIButton?) {}
```

Swift 3.0

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.subviews.forEach {
        ($0 as? UIButton)?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(someFunc(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
func someFunc(_ sender: UIButton?) {}
```

Comment: and how to add actions? where? and how? thanks Dmytro

Comment: @chronycles It's really pain to create all this buttons in storyboard

Comment: Exactly! that's why i'm so confused. i'm using swift 3 and using button not UiView, do i have to write the code as your code too? using view.subviews.forEach? or do i have to write like this seats.forEach { (seat) in
            seat.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButton), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        }

Comment: If you insert buttons in main View, then like my code. Because UIButton Is subview of UIVIew. And all your buttons, and views are stored in self.view.subviews. And What is seats ? if seats is collections of all buttons, yes seats.forEach

Comment: seats is collection of all buttons. and .touchUpInside is a listener when user touch the button, what if i want to use another listener, for example from server. When the server send data to specific button, the button color turns red or something. What should i do? Thanks

Comment: for what u say u create another func. When the server send data to specific button, u call this func just self.someFunc(seats[5]).

Comment: i have this error: reason: '-[UIButton copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd1424922f0'

Comment: I'am sorry, first time see this. Maybe it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784207/uilabel-copywithzone-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance

Answer (score 0):

you can use switch instead for loop here we go:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Button button2  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    ..
    ....Another buttons
    .....

    button.setOnClickListener(onClickButtons);
    button2.setOnClickListener(onClickButtons);

}

View.OnClickListener onClickButtons = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn1: // do smth 
                 break;
            case R.id.bt2: //do another thing
                break;
            ..
            ...
            ....
            default :
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: hi Sardor, is this java code? but i ask it on swift code. hehe.

Comment: Sorry bro , in that moment I thought it is Android in Java.